# Automatically installing PPAs

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, launchpad

After adding some PPAs from Launchpad to my repositiory (`add-apt-repository`) I want to install them automatically. As far as I know there is no command to install all new PPAs after `apt-get update`. And I can't run a script installing all new PPAs manually, because the install name of some PPAs differ to the name they have on the launchpad website/API.

Comment: It is unclear what is "install all PPAs". You can install packages from the connected ppa. Or just run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to install newer versions of already installed packages.

Comment: The normal way to go if you want to install a programm from a PPA, you have to do the following steps: 1. `add-apt-repository ppa` 2. `apt-get update` 3. `install ppa`. But the name which is necessary for the install command can differ from the name given on the launchpad site. That's why a automatic installation of a PPA is not always possible. clear?

Comment: There is no action "install ppa". PPA is an archive with packages.

Comment: I mean something like the 3. and 4. example [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/useful-ppas-for-ubuntu/)

Comment: The third attempt. PPA may contain many packages. You do not need to install them all in most cases.

Comment: You can make a script that will add the PPAs and then install the required packages.

Comment: In fact, trying to install them all is probably a mistake, and perhaps impossible (if packages conflict with each other).  I suspect that you are taking the wrong approach to what you want to do and so are describing the problem in a confusing way; see:   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  (better explanation here: http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: yes I can, but like in example 2 the install name can differ from the ppa name. That makes scripting difficult

Comment: A PPA can have many many many packages to install.  There's no automatic way to guess which one you might want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want to add a PPA to your system and automatically install all packages for your release and architecture that it provides.

**Disclaimer:** I am absolutely unsure if what you want to do is a good idea. But if you're truly insistent and proceed with caution, be my guest.

The lists of packages that can be installed from a repository are downloaded and stored in

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/
```

when `apt-get update` runs.

Those list files contain in plain text basically the information displayed when you do `apt-cache show <package>`. In particular each package has a field `Package: <name-of-package>`

Find here a Python script, that extracts all those `Package` fields and strings the package names together. Save it as `whatever.py` and run as `./whatever.py <packagelist>`. It will print the appropriate `apt-get install` command, but does not execute it (it couldn't because you're not running this as root, are you...?). This is up to you, and I strongly suggest you try with `-s` (simulate) first!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

if len(sys.argv)<2:
        print "Usage: "+sys.argv[0]+" PACKAGELIST"
        quit()

try:
        packages = []
        infile = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
        for line in infile:
                p = re.match(r"Package: (\S+)", line)
                if p:
                        packages.append(p.group(1))
        infile.close()
        print "apt-get install -s "+" ".join(packages)

except IOError:
        print "File "+sys.argv[1]+" not found."
```

For example:

[image]

If this produces truly the result you desire depends on the PPA and the packages in there.

**Use at your own risk.**